# printwriter object not printing out

Tags: java, javascript, methods, printwriter

My `PrintWriter` object writer's `print()` method isn't working, I imported all the appropriate classes but the CSV file keeps coming up blank., can anyone tell me why?

```
public class StateStats {
    static String pathto = "....";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
       ReadFile st = new ReadFile(pathto+"stateAbbrev.csv");
       ReadFile abPop = new ReadFile(pathto+"AbbrevPop.csv");      
       ReadFile Perc = new ReadFile(pathto+"PopPercentAlpha.dat");


       PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(pathto+"StateAbbPop.csv","UTF-8");

       //this is the header for our new CSV file
       writer.write("State, Abbrev, Population, %of US");
       writer.write("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you forgot to invoke `flush` or `close` on writer. Without it some temporary stored in buffer characters will not be send to file.

Comment: OMG  that was it!  its always the simplest of things with me!  thank you!